# jQuery .find('li').length must be from sibling/child?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a counter to count the number of li, but what I want to count lies in another element (section), and my jQuery setup with .find('li').length; don't want to work (I took it from another counter my teacher made for me, that works). Must the elements I want to count be siblings or children for it to work?

it's like, the one that works is basically built like this in html

```
<div>
<div><span>0</span></div>
<ul>
<li></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

while what I'm trying to do is more like this

```
<section>
<footer>
<div><span>0</span></div>
</footer>
</section>

<section>
<ul>
<li></li>
</ul>
</section>
```

my jQuery is currenly like this

```
var $name1 = $('.classname1 span'),
$name2 = $('.classname2 ul');

var name3 = $name2.find('li').lenght;
$name1.text(name3);
```

fair warning, I'm a newbie. I've only studied coding for 1,5 year.

Comment: Please correct length spelling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`don't want to work` That's one way of putting it :)) .

`element.find('li')` will find all the `li` which are descendants of that element. This includes children, grandchildren and so on. It's similar to `children()` method but this one only searches in the ' first ' level of descendants.

Second, the name is `length` not lenght as you write it.

See below

```js
// will return all 8 li
let liCount = $('ul.top-level').find('li').length 
console.log(liCount)


// will return just the top 5 ( direct children )
liCount = $('ul.top-level').children('li').length
console.log(liCount)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='top-level'>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li>
    <ul>
       <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  <li></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: yes, I carried on working on other things while waiting for replies, and then suddenly saw that I had spelled it wrong, and that was literally the only problem! I corrected it, and now it's working. But yes, thank you XD now I also know that it's not restricted to closest and so on!

Comment: Yes. First you need to learn how to ' ask google questions ' and find your answers by yourself. https://api.jquery.com/find/ . Then you need to be careful with the spelling. Use an IDE for that. In any code editor, writing lenght will return an error.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is get the element that contains all the `li`s you want to count, and then do `$el.find("li").length`.

How you get this element will vary depending on your situation. You can get it by targeting it directly (`$(#id_of_the_element)` or `$(.class_of_the_element)` for instance), or, if it's relative to another element, you can use methods like `closest`.

For me to help you more precisely, you'll have to post HTML that actually matches your JS code, as you HTML doesn't contain any classes.

Comment: my example is extremely simplified, I work with classes all over. Thank you for your reply, but I found the problem. This is emarrasing, but I spelled "length" wrong in my code *facepalm*